# Windows 10 command prompt is not recognizing any basic commands

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe, environment-variables, path

I have read forums, but have not found anything useful about what to do, with someone suggesting it might be with my `PATH` variable, but I don't know how to fix that.

- Output of `ipconfig`: [image: ipconfig output]
- Output of `PATH`:

  ```
  PATH=C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-8.0.242.08-openj9\bin;C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.6.10-openj9\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-14.0.0.36-openj9\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-13.0.2.8-hotspot\bin;C:\Program Files\aircrack-ng-1.6-win\aircrack-ng-1.6-win\bin;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Users\phili\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
  ```

  I do not know what the default is or whether this is any good: [image: Environment Variables]

Comment: Please give an example of a basic command which is not working, and what happens instead.

Comment: What exactly is your problem?  Can you please specific errors?

Answer (score 3):

You are missing these critical paths, I got these from a clean install of windows 10 1909:

> ```
> C:\WINDOWS\system32;
> C:\WINDOWS;
> C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;
> C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
> C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;
> C:\Users\<your User name here>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
> ```

There may be others you need to add for specific non windows programs to work correctly also.

Comment: Thank you, but where do I add those in

Comment: See this>>>>>>https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/

Comment: Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Let us know if this solves your issues, you are welcome.